# Mapbox GL js: How to enumerate all textfield properties

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to parse all `textfield` properties in a `foreach` to switch language with `Mapbox GL js`?
The goal is to write a working code even if we add/remove layer from the `editor`.

**EDIT**
For example in Mapbox Studio, we can use the properties editor to quickly change all `textfields`'s value from `{name_en}` to `{name_fr}`.
[image]
An [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/language-switch/) shows how to do it for one layer.
But how to parse all layers to find all `textfield` to change the language globally?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you give some more context, what you're trying to do, why you're trying to do it, and what's going wrong?

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ see my edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I understand right, you want to update every text field on every layer to reference a new set of properties ({foo_fr} vs {foo_en} or whatever), when the user changes language.

There's no way to automatically do that. But you can:

1. Iterate over every layer.
2. Iterate over a pre-defined set of properties that could contain language-specific text fields.
3. Update each.

The list in step 2 is going to be pretty short, maybe just `['text-field']`. So it's basically:

```
var newLanguageCode = 'ru';

map.getStyle().layers.forEach(layer => {
  if (layer.type === 'symbol' && layer.layout && layer.layout['text-field'] !== undefined) {
    map
      .setLayoutProperty(layer.id, 'text-field', layer.layout['text-field']
      .replace(/\{([^_]+)_..\}/, '{$1_' + newLanguageCode + '}');
  }
})
```

Comment: @steve-bennett-ㄹThat's exactly what I needed. thanks a lot.