# Mapbox GL js: How to enumerate all textfield properties to display a sub element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox

Is there a way to parse all textfield properties in a foreach display a sub element with Mapbox GL js? In my example I add a layer with the id `test` and want to add a title over a circle.

###### Code

```
map
    .current
    .addLayer({
        id: LOCATIONS_LAYER_ID,
        type: "circle",
        source: "locations",
        filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
        paint: {
            "circle-color": "#4264fb",
            "circle-radius": 6,
            "circle-stroke-width": 2,
            "circle-stroke-color": "#fff"
        }
    })
    .addLayer({
        id: "test",
        type: "symbol",
        source: "locations",
        filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
        layout: {
            "text-field": ['get', 'alias'],
            "text-variable-anchor": ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right'],
            "text-radial-offset": 1,
            "text-justify": 'auto',
        }
    })
```

I´ve tried a lot of ideas for example to change `"text-field": ['get', 'alias'],` to something like `"text-field": ['at', 0, ['get', 'alias']],`. Also a workaround like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562514/mapbox-gl-js-how-to-enumerate-all-textfield-properties) thread didn´t work.

###### Sample Data

[image]

I need to display a title in a MapBox symbol/circle.